# Apache Ant: Execute subsequent targets without waiting for completion

Tags: java, ant

first off, I've checked multiple posts, namely:
[Run Ant target in background without using spawn=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348960/run-ant-target-in-background-without-using-spawn-true)
and
[Ant target execution(Just execute, not wait to complete)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697596/ant-target-executionjust-execute-not-wait-to-complete)

Both didn't help.

I am working with Ant Apache and at the end of my script a .jar is created and a .zip file is created.

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
        <arg line="${args}"/>
    </java>
</target>

<target name= "zip" depends="run">
        <zip destfile="${zipname}" basedir=".">
</target>
```

If I do it like this, it will first run the jar, open a window of the program and wait for me to close said window before it runs the zip command.

However, I want it to run the .jar and create the zip file without waiting for the window created with run to be closed first. In simpler terms:
Run .jar and zip the file without waiting for run to be closed.

I tried doing it like this:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <parallel>
        <daemons>
            <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
                <arg line="${args}"/>
            </java>
        </daemons>
    <parallel>
</target>

<target name= "zip" depends="run">
        <zip destfile="${zipname}" basedir=".">
</target>
```

This almost seemed to work. The problem now was **the window that normally popped up when run was exected did not pop up** but the .zip file was created.

Is there any way to fix this or any alternative?

Thanks in advance

Also, on a sidenote: is it normal that while compile or jar etc. show messages (in the terminal, when running ant) run doesnt show any messages?

Comment: I guess my question would be: why are you designating `run` as a dependency of `zip` when, according to your description of the issue, `zip` doesn't actually depend on `run`? You can just make a third target that calls them both.

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true" spawn="true" >
    </java>
</target>
```

spawn="true" in java worked for me.